# Configuration issues with sdk U.are.U and visual c++

Tags: winforms, visual-c++, fingerprint

I am working with digital persona u.are.u sdk.I use  visual c++. I want to know how to configure visual c++ with the sdk libraries. Thanks
noubougg07@yahoo.fr

Comment: What have you already tried? [See this article on how to ask questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) (also you might want to remove your e-mail address)

Comment: try something: like read the developer's manual!

Comment: i read the developer's guide but nothing said about how to configure. thanks